# Tycho puts "p2" folder in the product with eclipse-repository and tycho-p2-director-plugin plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, maven-3, tycho

I changed my Tycho+Maven build (RCP application) to use Tycho 0.13 and eclipse-repository plus tycho-p2-director-plugin (instead of my old "eclipse-application" in Tycho 0.10).
I managed to get the build  working (producing the ZIP files), but they are 2 times bigger than they used to be.
I see Tycho puts a lot of additional stuff my product does not need:
1) "p2" folder at the root level - 35 Mb. 
2) a lot of useless plugins, like

```
plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.6.1.v20100715_r361
plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.6.2.R36x_20110203
plugins/org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100
......etc.........
```

how to configure "eclipse-repository" and "tycho-p2-director-plugin" to avoid this? At least to not put "p2" folder in the product. My software does not use "p2 update" mechanism for auto-updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing "archive-products" completely - it's not flexible and requires a lot of horrible hacking with unpacking/repacking/renaming. I'm packing the ZIP files  myself now:

```
<properties>
   <distributive.prefix>${project.build.directory}/products/taskadapter</distributive.prefix>
   <exclude_p2>**/p2/**</exclude_p2>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>materialize-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-zip-files</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target> 
                            <zip basedir="${distributive.prefix}/win32/win32/x86" 
                                 destfile="${project.build.directory}/taskadapter-win-${project.version}.zip"
                                 excludes="${exclude_p2}" />
                            <zip basedir="${distributive.prefix}/linux/gtk/x86" 
                                 destfile="${project.build.directory}/taskadapter-linuxgtk-${project.version}.zip"
                                 excludes="${exclude_p2}" />
                            <zip basedir="${distributive.prefix}/macosx/cocoa/x86" 
                                 destfile="${project.build.directory}/taskadapter-macos-${project.version}.zip"
                                 excludes="${exclude_p2}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

your product may drag in transitive optional dependencies.

See [1] for how to avoid this.

The p2/  folder is always created but should not be 35MB. 
If you can provide a sample project to reproduce the problem, open a bug [2] and attach it along with steps how to reproduce.

[1] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342704

[2] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All

Comment: Thanks, I'll try removing the optional dependencies, although it's sad that switching from eclipse-application to this new method introduced this problem. maybe I can just replace "require-bundle" with "import-package" and it'll solve the problem... we'll see.

the p2 folder has 30.5 Mb to be precise. this build is rather complicated now and I don't know how to reproduce it with a simple project. I can send the build scripts directly to you if you're willing to debug this Tycho issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. "p2" folder, the folder is created by p2 itself when materializing the product. if your application doesn't support update itself, you can simply remove it from the built product.
2. useless plugins. There is no way to remove them from your final materialized product, they are transitively required by your product. See [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg01515.html) for detail.

Comment: well, is there a way to tell Tycho to not put P2 folder into the product? if not (sad!), then what's the best way to remove it before the packaging?

Comment: The answer is no. P2 director always creates p2 folder for storing some data, such as which features/plug-ins are already installed.

Comment: @Alex, you can add ant task to unpackage the zip then create new one while excluding the p2 folder.

Comment: can I just delete the useless p2 folder BEFORE it's packaged into the ZIP file to avoid this weird step?..